# MrikoTik Source NAT With Pub IP's

Tags: networking, nat, mikrotik-routeros

Let me start off saying that I am use to FortiGate and have never programmed a MikroTik Router. I do have everything already built with the Private subnet but none of these publics added to the MikroTik and so far the private IP ranges are NAT through the customers pub IP (they have a single /30 WAN uplink) They have leased 3 blocks (2 /24 and 1 /28)

So the Customer wants to use a MiktoTik and this is the details. The ISP provided me 4 Public Networks, with the /30 being on the ISP device. lets say that these networks are as follows

1. 123.123.3.0/24
2. 123.123.5.0/24
3. 123.123.7.0/28

How would this be built to pass all these IP's to a VLAN with Source NAT and NAT POOL for blocks of Private addresses for "customer" devices to connect?

Private Subnet
10.10.10.0/22
10.11.11.0/22
10.12.12.0/24

Comment: This is the MikroTik that is being used. CCR1036-8G-2S+